# Kronecker product decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, kronecker-product

How can I decompose a matrix Z into two matrices X and Y as below:

$$
Z=X\otimes Y
$$

in which $\otimes$ is the kroncker product.
Is there any function in matlab or any other library which decomposes the kroncker product?

Comment: I assume that you found Matlab's [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) with a basic Google search?

Comment: i didn't get your mean. i am using the matrix normal distribution in the normal format, in this distribution kroncker product is used. i wanna convert a normal distribution to the matrix-normal format, so i should know how to inverse the kroncker product.

Answer (score -2):

it can be decomposed a matrix into X and Y. i don't have any proof for it but implemented a matlab code which do it. send me a message if u need it.

Comment: Not every matrix $Z$ can be decomposed like this (as a Kronecker product), so it makes sense you would not have a proof. Your answer might be more useful to Readers if you edited it to include an explanation of what assumptions are needed to get your "matlab code" to succeed.

Answer (score -2):

i didn't use any assumption for it, but tested my code for some real valued matrices and it worked. maybe it can be proofed but i am not sure about this . by the way i changed my mind and i don't use kroncker product any more but i will send the code here. it is a general function which can be used for any matrix. please let me know if there is any exception for it.

`%implemented by Sahar
%use the below codes for decomposition
% A1=[4 1 7;1 10 3; 5 9 2];
% B1=[2 2 3 ;2 5 1; 7 1 4];
% C=kron(A1,B1);
% [outA,outB]=decomposeKronecker(A1,B1,C)`

function [outA,outB]=decomposeKronecker(A1,B1,C)
C=triu(C);
A_sym = sym('A', size(A1));
B_sym = sym('B', size(B1));
C_sym=kron(A_sym,B_sym);
C_sym=triu(C_sym);
indx=find(C_sym);
equations=(C_sym(indx)==C(indx));
result=solve( equations);
A = sym('A',size(A1));
A=triu(A);
A_tril_sym=transpose(triu(A,1));
A=A+A_tril_sym;
outA=subs(A,result);
B = sym('B',size(B1));
B=triu(B);
B_tril_sym=transpose(triu(B,1));
B=B+B_tril_sym;
outB=subs(B,result);
kron(outA,outB)
end